# Pattern to match and replace words with upper and also lower case in them

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, expression

I have this problem with eliminating meaningless words from a string, for example:

> $string = "Hi, my name is Tom. jc2pMK NB,xVD NOZmF__u cYNdtR46eEb8y,74 Today i registered to stack overflow. krEBNB1cB8 cq7,zCL x5KOwwRZfU13.bI g_IXxlcztXYN ,    DPnmcgj2FyydHAx@ I like IT. 0T1LAkuoPXscYC5uK6mlG R1nix_5kwF ,EKxXvT1 SjZYC4A6YQ 4E";

Now I want to be able to search and destroy those meaningless words from there, in PHP. I was trying `preg_replace($pattern, "", $string)` but couldn't figure out a pattern for letting "Hi" stay there but deleting "jc2pMK". I bet this is an elementary procedure with strings, that every basic programmer should easily figure out, but I have no experience with regular expressions.

I am open minded about any other idea, how to get rid of the meaningless words.

Comment: What do you mean by "meaningless words". Is it "Words that contain a numeric character or underscore / comma not at the end"? Or do you really want to match any words not in the dictionary?

Comment: Can you define "meaningless" in this context? If you mean "contains an upper-case letter", is "JavaScript" meaningless? I am not a fan of txtspk at all, but does "you go 2 work" fail because of the 2? Or is a dictionary involved?

Comment: It's not an elementary procedure with strings. It's about semantics.

Comment: ok, the OUTPUT i wish to have from the string above is "Hi, my name is Tom. Today i registered to stack overflow. I like IT." The goal is delete everything except [a-z] and [A-Z] and words with one capital letter in them (ex. Hi, Tom, Today) yes JavaScript is bad

Comment: This is a seemingly impossible task to solve. You have provided no parameters to which we can limit the regex to.

Comment: There is no single regex solution for semantics. Do you agree?

Comment: The problem i was solving is a little deeper, this is a point where i am getting the sample text out of a formatted enviroment. Im getting sample text from a .doc, im using a script wich i found on StackOverFlow, but its keep giving me a couple of formatting on the end of the string. If im asking for impossible, im sorry, i have no clue about regex :) sorry for my bad ENG

Comment: @TomCheGuevara regex is about a set of regular characters in a certain order. Regex can't tell that `10` is actually the number `10`. Regex sees it as a `1` followed by a `0` with no meaning. For regex `10` is the same as `ad`. Regex can't tell that `Tom` is a boy's name or a cat's name. Regex can't tell that `H2O` is the molecule of water. If you want to,you need to define the rules. For example delete all the characters that begin with an uppercase,followed by a lower case followed by an uppercase `[A-Z][a-z][A-Z]` .IMO regex isn't the right tool.But you could use it if you don't mind errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone else commented, you aren't defining what a "meaningless word" is so it's impossible to answer your question. But, a regular expression that would work **ONLY** for your example `$string`, no guarantee for other strings, is the following:

Match (there's a space in front):

```
 (?:\w+[0-9_,@](?:\.\w)?\w*|[0-9.,]\w*)
```

Replace:

```
[leave empty]
```

You can test it online at [regex101](http://regex101.com/r/sE4rV3).

Here's the equivalent PHP code snippet:

```
$output = "Hi, my name is Tom. jc2pMK NB,xVD NOZmF__u cYNdtR46eEb8y,74 Today i registered to stack overflow. krEBNB1cB8 cq7,zCL x5KOwwRZfU13.bI g_IXxlcztXYN , DPnmcgj2FyydHAx@ I like IT. 0T1LAkuoPXscYC5uK6mlG R1nix_5kwF ,EKxXvT1 SjZYC4A6YQ 4E";
$result = preg_replace('/ (?:\w+[0-9_,@](?:\.\w)?\w*|[0-9.,]\w*)/',"",$output);
echo $result; #prints Hi, my name is Tom. Today i registered to stack overflow. I like IT.
```

Again, this only a **quick and dirty solution** for your specific string.

Comment: i see it working with the example above but in my code `preg_replace("(?:\w+[0-9_,@](?:\.\w)?\w*|[0-9.,]\w*)","",$output);` im getting "preg_replace(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 0" but thank you for the effort

Comment: it eliminated a couple of occurences of my "meaningless" words :) thank you for the quick effort, i think i can expand this somehow to get the things done, **thank you again**

Comment: You forgot the delimiters `/` around your regular expression and you forgot also the space in front of the match! For example: `$result = preg_replace('/ (?:\w+[0-9_,@](?:\.\w)?\w*|[0-9.,]\w*)/',"",$output); echo $result;`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve this on the semantic level, you'd need a dictionary of some sort. A poor man's approach would be to do something like

```
$dict = file('wordsEn.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
$string = "Hi, my name is Tom. jc2pMK NB,xVD NOZmF__u cYNdtR46eEb8y,74 Today i registered to stack overflow. krEBNB1cB8 cq7,zCL x5KOwwRZfU13.bI g_IXxlcztXYN , DPnmcgj2FyydHAx@ I like IT. 0T1LAkuoPXscYC5uK6mlG R1nix_5kwF ,EKxXvT1 SjZYC4A6YQ 4E";
$words = explode(' ', $string); // can also use str_word_count
echo implode (' ', array_intersect($words, $dict) );
```

This would load a dictionary into an array, split your string into an array and then create a diff to give you the words from your string that also exist in the dictionary. In the example's case, I used http://www-01.sil.org/linguistics/wordlists/english/wordlist/wordsEn.txt for a dictionary which would result in:

> my name is registered to stack like

The result will only be as good as your dictionary obviously. Also, the solution does not take casing into account. But it should give you an idea on how to approach the problem.

You'll find more sophisticated solutions in [PHP's Human Language and Character Encoding Support](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.international.php), for instance with the [Enchant](http://php.net/manual/en/book.enchant.php) and [PSpell](http://php.net/manual/en/book.enchant.php) extensions, which allow you to spell check words against dictionary files.